# Problema JasperReport Netbeans y Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jasper-reports

Buenas soy nuevo aquí pero quería pedirles ayuda por si alguien ya tuvo un problema similar.

Resulta que descargue  un sistema de ventas hecho en Java(Netbeans) que se conectaba a MySql,este hacia reportes con Japser, todo funcionaba OK. Decidí entonces cambiar de base de datos al Oracle 11g y logre hacerlo funcionando todo bien menos los reportes.

Cada que deseo que se genere el reporte en PDF me sale el siguiente mensaje de error en consola:

Error executing SQL statement for : null

Las consultas están bien... ya las probé... que podría ser?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto la url de donde saque el sistema:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pxaqk4atAhc&t=443s

**Info adicional:**
Al seleccionar el preview en el editor de jasper, si jala los datos correctos desde el Oracle.

[image: previsualización del reporte]

Comment: ¿Has cambiado el driver de conexión a base de datos de Mysql a Oracle?

Comment: Si la cambie,  funciona todo... las consultas, agregar, eliminar.... el problema es solo con el jasper... que no me genera los reportes, sin embargo en Mysql si

Comment: Igual el problema no es de la consulta y está en alguna field. Podrías probar a pintar solamente un valor de la consulta eliminando todo el resto e ir acotando el problema.

Comment: Podrías además poner el xml para ver qué más cosas podrían estar dando el problema. Ese null parece que es por no haberle puesto name al report. También ayudaría que mostraras el iReport output para ver la traza de log completa.

Comment: Ahora que me fijo también puede ser la referencia que estás haciendo al esquema CLIENTE_SERV. Si en oracle no has creado ese esquema/usuario, no va a encontrar la tabla.

Comment: Hola ante todo, Gracias por tomarte tu tiempo para responder.

Mira tal y como dije arriba el sistema funciona perfectamente en Mysql, que  es como lo conseguí, yo soy nuevo en esto y para practicar se me dio por migrarlo a Oracle.

Efectivamente logre hacerlo y todo funciona perfectamente, MENOS los reportes jasper.

El esquema CLIENTE_SERV si existe en mi base de datos, yo lo cree y lo coloque en la consulta del jasper para ver si ese era el problema (sin éxito alguno.

Comment: Aqui subí el jxml.

https://mega.nz/#!NWgEASjI!etkjesoWzT6AEXPx9QwxLlGFugm7oUTgQIHCrASrKrw

Comment: El ireport output no me muestra nada

Comment: El report está correcto, puede que me equivoque pero sigo pensando que el error está en la conexión, usuarios, esquemas, sinonimos o algo parecido. ¿La conexión la obtienes de la misma forma a la hora de generar el jasper que en el resto de la aplicación? Y otra cosa, ¿en el editor de consultas de ireport se previsualiza algún dato?

Comment: Agregué una captura mas a mi post, y si al abrir el xml en el  editor de jasper y seleccionar preview si jala la información correctamente.

Comment: Entonces es seguro que se trata de la forma en la que obtienes la conexión a traves del metodo 'conexion' de la clase conectar. (que por cierto por convención la clase debería ir con mayuscula la primera letra). Si es posible muestra el código de cómo obtienes la conexión y compáralo con otras consultas que haga la aplicación que sí devuelvan resultados.